# setup_environ in django

Tags: python, django

I used this syntax to change the setup_environ live settings from python shell

```
import live_settings
from django.core.management  import setup_environ
setup_environ(live_settings)
```

Is this change temporary or permanent?
Will we have to set it back to setup_environ(settings) to have the site function normally or by default the site will take settings instead of live_settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing it from the shell, the changes will only exist for the duration of that shell instance -- the stuff in `settings.py` will be used otherwise.

Comment: Or any other file passed via `--settings`.